# How do I use gstreamer to make an audio clip from a segment of a longer source?

Tags: python, audio, audio-streaming, gstreamer, segment

I would like to use gstreamer to save an arbitrary clip from one audio file to a new file. For example, a segment from 1 minute to 2 minutes in the original. How do I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need [gnonlin](http://wiki.pitivi.org/wiki/GNonLin_documentation). See http://www.jonobacon.org/2006/12/27/using-gnonlin-with-gstreamer-and-python/

You won't need a `gnlcomposition` because you only want one segment. Use a `gnlfilesource` with its start and duration set to 0, 1 minute, and media-start and media-duration set to 1 minute, 1 minute. All times and durations are in nanoseconds.

Take 5 seconds from `source.mp3` starting at 10 seconds, write to `destination.ogg`:

```
gst-launch-0.10 gnlfilesource location=$PWD/source.mp3 \
start=0 duration=5000000000 media-start=10000000000 media-duration=5000000000 ! \
audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! oggmux ! filesink location=destination.ogg
```