# splitting / segmenting video stream with gstreamer

Tags: video, gstreamer

Is there a way to split a video into segments of specified length? Ie 60 minute video into 12x5 mins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik, you will need to develop your own "segmenter". This is similar to what you need to create HTTP Live streaming files. There might be a simpler solution, but here is what I would do:

You can make a relative small program (in python) using multifilesink next-file=buffer (or next-file marker, if segments can't fit in memory).

You'll need to encode or demux your input stream, and mux the stream back. Cut the muxed stream on key-frame when the desired duration is reached, and push the aggregated buffer (or mark a fake key frame, for example, to force sink to create a new file). Reinitialize the muxer (or append muxer streamheader) to get file with correct header than can be played seperately (depending on the muxer).

Comment: I dumped gstreamer and wrote the segmenter using the FFMPEG libraries instead. Had to write an ugly C program for that ;-)

Answer (score 7):

It seems the "official" way to do this without reencoding and without losing frames is using the [`splitmuxsink`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-splitmuxsink.html) element:

For example for a MKV file input:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=input.mkv ! matroskademux ! h264parse ! splitmuxsink location=file%02d.mkv max-size-time=300000000000 muxer=matroskamux
```

The `max-size-time` gives the segment length in nanoseconds (sic), so the above value is 5 minutes. Because it cuts on keyframes, the real segment length will not be exactly 5 min but will vary by a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

`gnonlin` and `gnlfilesource` are made for this. You will have to transcode the video as part of the process since gstreamer does not have special support for splitting certain formats without transcoding.

See [How do I use gstreamer to make an audio clip from a segment of a longer source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215683/how-do-i-use-gstreamer-to-make-an-audio-clip-from-a-segment-of-a-longer-source) for an example of how to make clips from an audio file.

Answer (score 1):

FFMPEG has a built in segment demuxer.

check the -segment option n the documention.

http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#segment

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish something similar using Perl with the GStreamer and GLib bindings. My hack abuses the GStreamer Pipeline state in order to reset the filesink's location. I use a streaming source and hence the reset to zero behavior after set_state('null') is acceptable. You will need to manage the seek position in your source element in order to support proper segmentation.

```
my $g_pipeline = GStreamer::Pipeline->new('pipeline');
....
my $g_filesink  = GStreamer::ElementFactory->make(filesink  =>  "filesink");
$g_filesink->set(location => $file_name);
...
$g_pipeline->add(..., $g_filesink);

my $delay = 5000; # switch output file at this interval
my $timer = Glib::Timeout->add( $delay, 
  sub {
    $g_pipeline->set_state('null');
    ...
    $g_filesink->set(location=> $next_file_name);
    $g_pipeline->set_state('playing');
  }
);
```